# Converting radiobuttons into checkboxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button

I've a set of radio buttons and a checkbox on the page like below

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Languages</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span>What languages do you know?</span>
    <form action="">
    <div id="controlArea">
        <input type="radio" name="lanRadio" value="radioRussian"><label for="radioRussian">Russian</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="lanRadio" value="radioEnglish"><label for="radioRussian">English</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="lanRadio" value="radioSpain"><label for="radioRussian">Spain</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="lanRadio" value="radioFrench"><label for="radioRussian">French</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkIn" value="CheckMore"><label for="CheckMore">More than 1</label><br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

What I want to do is, if a user checks the "More than 1" checkbox, all radio buttons must turn into checkboxes and users must be able to check more options. If the user unchecks the checkbox, all the checkboxes must turn back into a set of radio buttons. When changing radiobuttons to checkboxes, the selected radio button must become the checked checkbox.

Comment: need it for today, no jquery, no innerHTML, ready to use code... anything else?

Comment: Th0rndike, that is all, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
function morethan(cbox) {
    // setup new state
    var state = "radio";
    if (cbox.checked) {
        state = "checkbox";
    }
    // get all by name and change state
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('lanRadio');
    for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        radios[i].type = state;
    }
}​
```

You need to add an `onclick` handler to your checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkIn" onclick="morethan(this)" value="CheckMore">
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/xEZyH/)

Comment: it's working in chrome only. but i need this to work in all modern browsers. also, inappropriate behavior in chrome: if first and second checkboxes are selected, it applies to the second radio button when converting back to radio buttons. actually it must apply to first selected checkbox. **please let me finish this.**

Comment: @user1271160 not sure what the cross browser issues are .. it works for me in Firefox and Chrome - perhaps you can provide some more information ?

Comment: when converting radio to checkbox, selected radio must become to a selected checkbox. and when converting checkbox to radio, the first selected checkbox must become a selected radio.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . Just copy and paste my code

```
        <html>
    <head>
        <title>Languages</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.getElementById("radio1").type=="radio")
        {
        document.getElementById("radio1").type="checkbox";
        document.getElementById("radio2").type="checkbox";
        document.getElementById("radio3").type="checkbox";
        document.getElementById("radio4").type="checkbox";
        }
        else
        {
        document.getElementById("radio1").type="radio";
        document.getElementById("radio2").type="radio";
        document.getElementById("radio3").type="radio";
        document.getElementById("radio4").type="radio";
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>What languages do you know?</span>
        <form action="">
        <div id="controlArea">
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="lanRadio" value="radioRussian"><label for="radioRussian">Russian</label><br />
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="lanRadio" value="radioEnglish"><label for="radioRussian">English</label><br />
            <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="lanRadio" value="radioSpain"><label for="radioRussian">Spain</label><br />
            <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="lanRadio" value="radioFrench"><label for="radioRussian">French</label><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkIn" value="CheckMore" onchange="fnc()"><label for="CheckMore">More than 1</label><br />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: not worked. i checked the check box, and nothing changed. :-(. maybe something is missing. i don't know

Comment: Thats may I forgot to close the html tag. But it works fine in my local and easier code to understand